# Background turned black while trying to catch a rattata

Tags: pokemon-go

I clicked on the rattata on the map and it did the small intro animation after that the background on the catch screen, I don't use AR, turned black from the bottom to the top. The rattata was still visible and jumped up and down and thw circle also still worked. However all other icons including the Pokeball vanised.

[image: Screenshot from the rattata with black background]

I didn't manage to reproduce this, so I don't know what caused it. The only way to fix it was to restart the app.
Has anyone encountered something similar, or knows the cause?

Comment: I encountered that while catching a Pidgey.
So I killed the app and then it never happened again.
So many Pidgeys in my bag, the game doesn't seem to accept more xDD

Comment: Device problem.. this usually happens when ressoures are running low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs when you throw a Pokéball at the wrong time.
Is it possible you used the glitch "trying to throw the ball repeatedly before the Pokémon is ready and catch ring appears"?
While trying to catch Pokémon this way gives you a very high chance of capturing it with a great or higher ball, there is a chance you trigger this effect.
The dark thing you see is the shadow of the Pokéball which seems to get closer and closer to the imaginery light source.
To end this bug you need to restart the game (and maybe try to throw your balls the right way)

Comment: I did not know about this glitch.  But it sounds possible since I sometimes just tap around the screen during the animation

Answer (score 1):

To explain what is actually occurring:

The ball is getting stuck under the Rattata's body when you toss it so quickly, which causes it to glitch through the floor. This can also happen with Weedle and likely other Pokémon that start the battle very close to you.

The math used to draw the shadow of the Pokéball onto the ground will decrease the size of the shadow the higher the Pokéball goes and increase it as the Pokéball gets lower. When the Pokéball goes through the floor, it falls infinitely in the void and the size of the shadow continues to get larger and larger, forever.

Since the ball doesn't collide with the floor, the game doesn't consider it a completed throw. A throw is completed when the ball collides with the Pokémon or the floor, after which it animates for about a second longer before selecting your next Pokéball. The only solution is to restart your app and curse at the Rattata.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me (even with a rattata). As just happened once, i think it is app or server failure. I didnt give too much thought about it.